# System.FormatException Input String was not in correct format

Tags: c#, xml, string, serialization

I am calling a web service (http://codes.eglencefabrikasi.com/Services/service.php?wsdl)  and when I am making a call via Wizdler or Soap-ui, I have no problem. But when I call from my source code like

```
            var service = new EFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16
            {
                Url =http://codes.eglencefabrikasi.com/Services/service.php,
                Timeout = 50000
            };

var response = service.finalizeDay(14, "13-03-2017");
```

I get the error below. Any ideas? Thanks up-front

---

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 858). ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info,
>   Boolean parseDecimal)    at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s,
>   NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadTypedPrimitive(XmlQualifiedName
>   type, Boolean elementCanBeType)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String
>   name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderEFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16.Read4_NullableOfInt32(Boolean
>   checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderEFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16.Read3_transactions()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String
>   name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadArray(String
>   typeName, String typeNs)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String
>   name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderEFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16.Read6_finalize()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String
>   name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadArray(String
>   typeName, String typeNs)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencingElement(String
>   name, String ns, Boolean elementCanBeType, String& fixupReference)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderEFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16.Read32_finalizeDayResponse()
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Intertech.Application.Operation.EFDigital.EFDigitalCodesWebServicesV16.finalizeDay(Int32
>   instutionId, String date) in
>   C:\Tfs\DFHG\DEV\FastPayBackEnd\Intertech.Fortuna.Layers\Application.Layer\Intertech.Application.Operation\Web
>   References\EFDigital\Reference.cs:line 590    at
>   Intertech.MobileMoneyTransfer.Utility.FastPayUtility.FunFactoryDailyReconciliation()
>   in
>   C:\Tfs\DFHG\DEV\FastPayBackEnd\Intertech.Fortuna.Layers\MobileMoneyTransfer.Layer\Intertech.MobileMoneyTransfer.Utility\FastPayUtility.cs:line
>   522    at
>   Intertech.MobileMoneyTransfer.WebApp.FastPay.FunFactoryDailyReconciliation()
>   in
>   C:\Tfs\DFHG\DEV\FastPayBackEnd\Intertech.Fortuna.Layers\MobileMoneyTransfer.Layer\Intertech.MobileMoneyTransfer.WebApp\FastPay.asmx.cs:line
>   1317

Comment: what is `service`?

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: I see an exception triggered by a StringToNumber method. Where is the string that should be converted to a number here?

Comment: You are missing the xml identification line (1st line).  I sometime add following to beginning of the xml string : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: I editted the question with "service" definition,

Comment: StringToNumber method -> I assume the problem is about this "13-03-2017" part, but i am not sure of course

Comment: I can consume other methods of this web service, no problem. But can't handle this one

Comment: @YalçınAktaş any luck?

Comment: Thanks guys, but we figure out the real problem was in the service itself. They managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you use the `Url` as

`var url = new Url("http://codes.eglencefabrikasi.com/Services/service.php");`

This way you won't get any string formatting errors.